# Botão com loading animação - Bootstrap v4.1.1

Tags: css3

Segue JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3w4861v/3/

Segue código:

```css
.sk-cube-grid {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 16px auto;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #333;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
  0%,
  70%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
  0%,
  70%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
<div class="sk-cube-grid">
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
</div>
Carregando
</button>
```

A ideia é colocar animação do lodo direito ou esquerdo da palavra "carregando", algo parecido com isso:

```
|=================|
|  **  Carregando |
|=================|
```

ou

```
|=================|
|  Carregando  ** |
|=================|
```

Asterisco(**) é animação. Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a altura da animação é fixa bem como as margens, você pode usar `line-height` com esses valores, que dá `62px` no total e adicionar no botão:

```
button.btn-outline-primary{
  line-height: 62px;
}
```

Para alinhar à esquerda, você pode usar a classe do Bootstrap `float-left` na `div` pai da animação. Também é preciso alterar as margens da animação para não ficar grudado ao texto (usei `10px` na margem direita, mas você pode usar o que quiser):

```
.sk-cube-grid {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 16px 10px 0 0;
}               ↑
          margem direita
```

Se quiser a animação à direita, use a classe `float-right` e ajuste a margem à esquerda:

```
.sk-cube-grid {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 10px;
    }               ↑
              margem esquerda
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
button.btn-outline-primary{
  line-height: 62px;
}

.sk-cube-grid {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 16px 10px 0 0;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #333;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
  0%,
  70%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
  0%,
  70%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
<div class="sk-cube-grid float-left">
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
</div>
<span>Carregando</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Era isso que eu queria, obrigado @dvd